# Error CS0411 The type arguments for method 'Program.Binary_Search(T[], T, IComparer)' cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, algorithm, interface, binary-search

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

I am getting this error message for my Binary search method.

> Error CS0411  The type arguments for method
>   'Program.Binary_Search(T[], T, IComparer)' cannot be inferred
>   from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

```
      //Binary search method.
    public static void BinarySearch<T>(T[] data)
    {
        Binary_Search(data, Console.ReadLine(), Comparer<T>.Default);
    }
```

---

```
        //Binary search algorithm
        public static int Binary_Search<T>(T[] data, T searchFor, IComparer<T>comparer)
        {
            int high, low, mid;
            high = data.Length - 1;
            low = 0;
            //if the first element of the array is what I'm looking for then return that element.
            if (data[0].Equals(searchFor))
                return 0;
            //else if highest element in the array is the item im looking for then return the element.
            else if (data[high].Equals(searchFor))
                return high;
            else
            {
                //While low point is lower than or equal with high point set the mid point to be in the middle of the highest and lowers point.
                while (low <= high)
                {
                    mid = (high + low) / 2;
                    //Compare mid point to the item searched, if the difference is 0 it means the item is there, return the element.
                    if (comparer.Compare(data[mid], searchFor) == 0)
                        return mid;
                    //Else if the difference between mid point and searched item is bigger than 0, the searched item must be lower than mid point,
                    //set the new high point to be current mid -1;
                    else if (comparer.Compare(data[mid], searchFor) > 0)
                        high = mid - 1;
                    //Else (Current mid point is lower than the searched item) set the new low point to be the current mid point +1.
                    else
                        low = mid + 1;
                }
                return -1;
            }
        }
```

---

Main program

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Analysis of Seismic Data.\n");
                //Read in the files and put them into arrays.
                String[] Years = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Year_1.txt");
                String[] Months = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Month_1.txt");
                String[] Days = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Day_1.txt");
                String[] Times = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Time_1.txt");
                String[] Depths = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Depth_1.txt");
                String[] Latitudes = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Latitude_1.txt");
                String[] Longitudes = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Longitude_1.txt");
                String[] Magnitudes = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Magnitude_1.txt");
                String[] Regions = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Region_1.txt");
                String[] IRIS_IDs = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\IRIS_ID_1.txt");
                String[] Timestamps = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data\Timestamp_1.txt");
        //Read in user's decision.
        Console.Write("Select which Collection is to be analysed: ");

        int collectionDecision = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //Selected which collection is to be analyzed
        switch (collectionDecision)
        {
            case 1:
                //Create another switch statement to select either ascending or descending sort.
                Console.WriteLine("\nWould you like to sort the Collection in Ascending or Descending order?");
                Console.WriteLine("1-Ascending");
                Console.WriteLine("2-Descending");
                int sortingDecision = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (sortingDecision)
                {
                    case 1:
                        //Using the default QuickSort option to sort the collection in an ascending order.
                        QuickSort(Years);
                        Console.WriteLine("Contents of the Ascending Year Collection: ");
                        foreach (var year in Years)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(year);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the Number/Name of the items you are looking for from the previously selected Collection.");
                        Console.Write("Search: ");
                        //How do I implement Binary Search here to search for specific items from a selected Array/Collection and display them?

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //Using Comparer<T>.Create to create a custom object and change the algorithm to sort in a Descending order.
                        QuickSort(Years, Comparer<string>.Create((a, b) => b.CompareTo(a)));
                        Console.WriteLine("Contents of the Descending Year Collection: ");
                        foreach (var year in Years)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(year);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the Number/Name of the items you are looking for from the previously selected Collection.");
                        Console.Write("Search: ");
                        //How do I implement Binary Search here to search for specific items from a selected Array/Collection and display them?
                        break;

                }
                break;
```

I am trying to make an application where the User chooses which array they want to search, once the array is selected the user sorts the array and after that the user gets the option to search for specific items from the array using Binary Search. For example if the user is in the Years array they can enter "2016" and the Binary search will search out all the 2016 items from the list and display them on console. The String arrays contain different data types: ints, strings, doubles.

Comment: Why would `Console.ReadLine()` match `T`?

Comment: @Idos I thought I created a BinarySearch method that when called I set the array as parameter and then when I run the application the Console.ReadLine is used to search for any data type from the array. My understanding of generic types is very low, what should I use instead of Console.ReadLine then?

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` returns a `string`, you have to provide to your `Binary_Search` method an instance of `T`, which, of course, matches the array you are giving as first argument.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I don't understand how to pass an instance of T to my method, I need an example.

Comment: I believe it is better if you explain what you are trying to achieve. From the code you posted there seems to be no way to understand what do you want your application to do. Please try to be more specific in what do you expect your code to do (what inputs, what outputs: print something, show a message, etc.).

Comment: To start, your method BinarySearch that calls Binary_Search doesn't really do anything. It doesn't return anything and it doesn't do anything with the result of the binary search. An example input could be anything that is comparable. An int, a string, a date, etc. Console.ReadLine() would make sense in a different context as long as the array of data is also of type string[]. The reason you're getting an error with it is that the compiler doesn't know that you want T[] to actually be string[] when you used a string (Console.ReadLine()) as the input.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I updated the post with more code and information for better context

Comment: @Ulfren more questions arise: *Binary search will search out all the 2016 items from the list and display them* that's not how binary search works, it finds the first matching item index, not *all*. Also, binary search will not work if the array is not ordered in ascending order (if you use the default comparer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is a quick-a-dirty example on how your `Binary_Search` method works with strings:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value to search:");

    var toSearch = Console.ReadLine();

    var strings = GetOrderedArrayOfStrings(); // assuming here we have an ordered string[]

    var position = Binary_Search(strings, toSearch, Comparer<string>.Default);

    if(position == -1)
        Console.WriteLine("Not found");
    else
        Console.WriteLine($"Found at position {position}");
}
```

The error message you are seeing is because the compiler wants an instance of `T` (and not a `string`, which is not the same as the generic type you declared) inside your method.

Comment: Amazing, I understand this so much better now, Thanks a lot for the help.
And yeah... it will only print one found element, I will be looking into how to modify my binary search so that it prints out all the values. Or maybe use a different searching algorithm better suited for duplicates? Each array contains only 600 elements so im not too worried about the time complexity.